# Toggle elements if they have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to toggle elements of a set, according to if they have a certain class or not using a [boolean parameter](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)? I tried the following approach but I think `$(this)` doesn't relate to the `".person"`

```
// Would show the entries with the selected country, hide the others
function toggleCountries(country){
    $(".person").toggle( $(this).hasClass(country) );
}
```

DOM:

```
...
<select onchange="toggleCountries($(this).val())">
     <option value="usa">USA</option>
     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
     ...
</select>
...
<li class="person usa"></li>
<li class="person canada"></li>
<li class="person canada"></li>
<li class="person mexico"></li>
...
```

**Sidenote**: I know how to toggle the elements using multiple lines but I'm curious if there is a one-line way of doing it for future reference, could be useful.

Comment: $(".person.canada").toggle()

Comment: What exactly does toggling your list elements do? Out of curiousity

Comment: There is a dropdown that will show/hide the elements, I'll put more details in my question :)

Comment: So when changing the select, what should happen to your list?

Comment: The <li> with the selected country are shown, the other hidden... damn sorry guys, I thought my question was simple and didn't realize there was so much room for misinterpretation :/

Comment: Note that you have a typo in your option's values. It's `value` not `val`

Comment: Doing things in a single line for the sake of doing things in a single line is the way of the dark side of the force. Instead, strive to make your code easy to read and understand. That way leads to the light.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I'm using this situation as an example to know if it's possible to access $(this) inside the "toggle" function, as knowing how to use this could prove useful in other situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.*** You can use function parameter `country` inside `toggle()` as a boolean like below

```
function toggleCountries(country){
  $(".person").each(function(){
    $(this).toggle(!$(this).hasClass(country.toLowerCase()));
  });
}
```

***2*** `val` need to be `value` in ***select-box option***

***Working snippet:-***

```js
/*function toggleCountries(country){
  $(".person."+country.toLowerCase()).toggle();
}*/

function toggleCountries(country){
  $(".person").each(function(){
    $(this).toggle(!$(this).hasClass(country.toLowerCase()));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="toggleCountries($(this).val())">
     <option value="usa">USA</option>
     <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>


<li class="person usa">q</li>
<li class="person canada">m</li>
<li class="person canada">n</li>
<li class="person mexico">b</li>
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question, and thanks a lot for your help friend.. however I need a boolean value as a param in the "toggle()" method to show or hide the element

Comment: Wrap in a foreach loop huh? I was thinking about doing this as well but wasn't sure if there was another way :) Ok then, I guess that's the way to do it, thanks friend!

Comment: @user2608458 glad to help you :):)